# PC won't connect to internet. "No internet, secured"

Tags: networking, internet

"No internet, secured" is displayed when "connected" to a network.

The below event appeared when internet stopped working.
**Event 4307 "Initialization failed because transport refused to open initial address"**

nbtstat -n is showing no names

I tried...

- New network adapter
- Connect to different networks - router and phone hotspot
- Uninstalled network drivers
- Wired and wireless
- ipconfig /release && ipconfig /renew
- netsh int ip reset
- netsh winsock reset
- sfc /scannow
- statically assigned IP address

Other info

- Windows 10 Home OS
- Realtek PCIe Network Controller / LAN driver
- Other devices connect successfully on same network
- PC Manufacturer ASUS Desktop

Am I left with wiping the PC?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the [suggestions here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/netbt-4307-error-after-windows-update/7799eb92-4fca-48b6-bac6-996042c94197)

Comment: Yep, first post that shows up in google.

Comment: Had a similar issue on a specific network because I had I set DNS resolution manually (Cloudflare). That network allowed only their own DNS resolution. Try setting that to automatic.

Comment: The PC is on my personal network, all settings automatic. I have no issues with other PCs / devices connecting on same network. I also tried connecting the problem PC to my phone's hotspot, same error.

Comment: What sort of PC? Which OS? What version? What network adapters? What sort of network? Re "Tried a bunch of commands", please list ALL of the commands you tried, and the output of each. While you tried different networks, were all the networks you tried wireless? Have you tried a wired network? What network drivers did you try? Are other devices able to connect successfully on the same networks you have troubles on? What happened immediately preceding this occurring for the first time? Please EDIT your question to add further information to help us better understand your situation.

Comment: I added some additional details. Will add specific model / version info later when home.

Answer (score 0):

Not really the solution I'd like but I no longer had time to troubleshoot. I used Windows reset with keeping personal files option. I was able to connect to internet again after doing so.